# Creating object by Polymorphic association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I need (or I think) implement polymorphic association in my model but I have something wrong. Let see my situation, it's a simple question/answers system, and the logic is the following:
- a question can be ansewered by N answers.
- An answer can be only a "text" XOR (one or other, not both) a "picture".

**Migrations:**

```
class CreateAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :answers do |t|
            t.integer :question_id
            t.references :answerable, :polymorphic => true
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end

class CreateAnswerTexts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :answer_texts do |t|
            t.text :content

            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end

class CreateAnswerPictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :answer_pictures do |t|
            t.string :content

            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

**Models**
**answer.rb**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user_id
    belongs_to :question_id
    belongs_to :answerable, :polymorphic => true

    attr_accessible :answerable_type
end
```

**answer_text.rb**

```
class AnswerText < ActiveRecord::Base
    TYPE = "text"

    has_one :answer, :as => :answerable

    attr_accessible :content
end
```

**answer_picture.rb**

```
class AnswerPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
    TYPE = "picture"

    has_one :answer, :as => :answerable

    attr_accessible :content
end
```

**Controller
answers_controller.rb:**

```
...
def create
    post = params[:answer]
    create_answerable(post[:answerable_type], post[:answerable])
    @answer = @answerable.answer.new()
end

private
def create_answerable(type, content)
    @answerable = ('Answer' + type.capitalize).classify.constantize.new(:content => content)
    @answerable.save
end
...
```

**And view form (Only have these fields):**

```
...
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :answerable_type %><br />
<%= select("answer", "answerable_type", Answer::Types, {:include_blank => true}) %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :answerable %><br />
<%= f.text_field :answerable %>
</div>
...
```

So, the problem is when I submit form I get this error:

> undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
>   app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:52:in`create'

Answers? :)

Comment: Hmm not sure if it is relevant but I would use `attr_accessible :answerable_type, :answerable_id`

Comment: what does @answerable.answer.class return after create_answerable in the create method?

Comment: @awenkhh create_answerable creates an instance of inherited class (AnswerText, or AnswerPicture) according at param type ("text", or "picture").

Comment: Try change `create_answerable(post[:answerable_type], post[:answerable])` to `@answerable = create_answerable(post[:answerable_type], post[:answerable])`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

on a `has_one` relationship, you have to use :

```
@answerable.build_answer
```

or

```
@answerable.create_answer
```

instead of

```
@answerable.answer.new
```

see [the reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I had to use @answerable.create_answer.

Comment: and try (@answerable.answer || @answerable.create_answer) if answer might already exist